# Why is my webpack-serve building so much SLOWER than webpack-dev-server?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr, webpack-serve

I'm finding that `webpack-serve` is taking a lot longer to build than `webpack-dev-server`. I have both of them set up at the same time, as shown in the image below. `-serve` takes twice as long for the initial build and about 10x as long for a simple hot build. They are both set up in the same way, using a proxy to serve up the non-webpack'd content from the real server. Other than that, it's all the default settings.

If `webpack-serve` is supposed to be "lightning fast" compared to `wds`, why is mine taking so much longer?

[image: webpack-serve vs webpack-dev-server]

Comment: I forgot to mention: Another issue I'm having is that with WDS, the page is hot-reloaded (without refreshing), but with webpack-serve, the it logs "Cannot apply update. Please refresh the page.", and then of course it auto-refreshes the whole page.

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED: `mode` was set to `production` instead of `development` (and therefore UglifyJSPlugin was wasting all the time on each build).

I thought I had it set up right, using `mode: process.env.WEBPACK_SERVE ? 'development' : 'production'` in my main `webpack.js` config file. However, because I wasn't using the `webpack-serve` CLI, it wasn't actually setting that `env` variable. (I have it setup to use the `serve()` function)

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to solve the issue is to add the `--mode development` flag.

```
webpack serve --mode development
```